# How to get my code to run at any worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA so please be patient as this all is new to me :)
Below code works great. It will unmerge cells if merged through column A of active worksheet and fill with duplicates. It's placed in module 17 for worksheet "Paste DATA". I would like to run this code on any worksheet if need. For example if for data inside in worksheet " Paste Additional Data " need to use this code i could use it by changing target worksheet name inside code. Same with range - change range by adjusting manually inside code.

```
Sub Unmerge_Cells_test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(Lr, 1).Select
            Lr = Lr + Selection.Cells.Count - 1
            
Range("A2:A" & Lr).UnMerge
    For R = 3 To Lr
        If Cells(R, 1) = "" Then Cells(R, 1) = Cells(R - 1, 1)
Next R

End Sub
```

Comment: I am confused as to what you are asking. You want to know how to adjust the ranges/worksheet name/workbook name inside the code?

Comment: "It's placed in module 17 for worksheet "Paste DATA"." What does this mean? Your VBA project has a folder called "Microsoft Excel Objects", which contains an entry for each Worksheet, and a folder called "Modules". Which folder is your code in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. Copy it in a standard module:

```
Sub Unmerge_Cells_test()
 'Please, cultivate the habit to declare all used variables:
 Dim LR As Long, r As Long, sh As Worksheet

 'here you set the "any sheet" you need:
 Set sh = Worksheets("TheSheetYouNeed") 'or ActiveSheet to test what it does now...

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LR = sh.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
            
    sh.Range("A2:A" & LR).UnMerge
    For r = 3 To LR
        If sh.cells(r, 1) = "" Then sh.cells(r, 1) = sh.cells(r - 1, 1)
    Next r
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Minor point, but should the code remember the pre-existing setting of ScreenUpdating before changing it to False?

Comment: @DS_London: Why should the code do that? Do you think that is it possible to work with `ScreenUpdating = false`? It looked obvious for me that he missed the line `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. Otherwise, he could not see the processing result. Am I missing something? I cannot get your point, sorry...

Comment: @FaneDuru it works great. Thank u for advice, i will stick to this habit :)

Comment: Why do you assume ScreenUpdating is True when the subroutine starts?

Comment: @DS_London: Why should I care about it? What would be wrong if it is already `False`? The `Sub` is not in a loop. It works for a specific worksheet. Only once after start running it. If it does not end with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`, you could not see the processing result. Why loosing time with another code line to check something completely useless? What reason do you imagine for such a behavior?

Comment: As I said "a minor point", and it could well make no difference in this example. But let's say the user decided to journey further into VBA and write a subroutine which called Umerge_cells_test, but which also did other lengthy operations. The calling Sub might well set ScreenUpdating=False at the start, and back to True at the end: if Unmerge_cells_test sets ScreenUpdating=True regardless of the initial state, then the calling Sub may not operate as hoped. I've got into the habit of leaving these "global" application variables the way I found them ... but not everyone agrees clearly!

Comment: @DS_London:  I cannot get you, even if I try. I consider I spent much more time then necessary on a issue which does not bring any benefit. At least, on my test... I wish you a good day!

Comment: "What would be wrong if it is already False?" ... because presumably it was set to False for a reason. Now you've set it to True regardless. Anyhow, the questioner seems happy enough, and is grateful that you have spent time answering their question, so let's leave it.

Comment: @DS_London: This is at least strange... Where is the problem if "it was set to False for a reason", if **anyhow, the code makes it `True` at the end**? And can you explain us **at least a (good) reason to make it False**, which I must confess I would consider a stupid idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225628/discussion-between-ds-london-and-faneduru).

Comment: Actually I will put this here, as it might help others. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating . Application.ScreenUpdating is a READ/write property, so you can test it. So ... Dim b as Boolean /  b = Application.ScreenUpdating /  Application.ScreenUpdating = False / .... Do the work / Application.ScreenUpdating = b

Comment: So you save the state of ScreenUpdating, change it to False while your code does its thing, then re-set to the original state. If if was True when the Sub was called it is True when the Sub exits, if it was False, it stays False.

Comment: @DS_London: Your example does  not prove anything. It is specially created to prove the difference between using the events pair or not. And **it ends in `Application.EnableEvents = True`**. Otherwise, you could not even observe the difference... I started to have the feeling that we are loosing time. I wish you a good day!